# Combine overlapping pictures

Tags: pictures, crop

I took series of screenshots and I need to combine them into single picture. It contains very big excel sheet. I know that there is software for creating panorama picture from series of photos. The screenshots shall be much easier to combine, but I failed to find any software to achieve this effect. Google found just solutions for photos and if I try them they refuse to work on ordinary pictures. Any hint? Otherwise I will have to manipulate it by hand :-(

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. If you can tell us what you have done so far and ask a specific question about where you are stuck, it would be on topic.

Comment: How many pictures?

Comment: 8 Pictures. I tested all free products mentioned in wikipedia topic. I sit at different computer now. Tbs most promising was the one from Microsoft labs. I could arrange pictures into a matrix 4x2 but next step failed.

Comment: enblend, hugin, Microsoft image composite editor, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_stitching_applications

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at this link. It describes how to do this with Paint. I did it several years ago when piecing together multiple scans of a large map.

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Stitch-your-Panorama-Photos-with-Paint/

-Mike

Comment: I have done similar approach already but I hoped I could automate it.

Comment: Might try something like this... http://zippyhelp.com/imagetools/stitch/photostitch.htm or http://www.serif.com/free-panoramic-photo-stitching-software/